# Local variables and garbage generation

Tags: c#

There is a piece of my code which is called repeatedly (2000+ each second).
To avoid garbage generation and to reduce performance overhead, I moved all local variables to class level, but I'm not sure if this approach is effective...

My question is...

- When the local variables are being collected by the garbage collector?
- Does moving local variables to class level boost performance and reduce garbage generation?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the method looks like?

Comment: Did you measure anything? I would say turning local vars into fields would be slower and a nightmare for threading. But it depends.

Comment: No measures is done, and it is indeed threading nightmare, also it may consumes more memory per object, and it may slow down initial object allocation in memory, but does it reduce garbage generation or boost performance? by using already allocated memory for a time critical methods.

Comment: Impossible to say, you'll have to show examples at least. But then it still depends on the whole situation. Best advice: don't solve a problem you don't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this very simple example (where `SomeObject` is a class, not a struct):

```
class C
{
  void MethodCalledMillionsOfTimes()
  {
    var so = new SomeObject();
    // some use of so
  }
}
```

Each time the method is called, one new object is created on the heap. It needs to be garbage collected some time after the use of it has ended. That is one object to collect per call of the method.

Then suppose it is changed into:

```
class C
{
  SomeObject soField;

  void MethodCalledMillionsOfTimes()
  {
    soField = new SomeObject();
    // some use of soField
  }
}
```

This changes nothing! You still create one new instance for each method call. The garbage collector has to do the same amount of work.

But what if you did:

```
class C
{
  SomeObject soField = new SomeObject();

  void MethodCalledMillionsOfTimes()
  {
    // some use of soField
  }
}
```

This time the same object is re-used each time the method is called again on the same instance. So fewer objects need to be garbage collected (assuming the method is actually called many times on the same `C` object). Note that this can only work if the `SomeObject` instance can be used many times, and does not have its state "ruined" by each use.

If many threads call the method at once, be sure the object `soField` can handle that.

If you go further and say:

```
class C
{
  static SomeObject soStaticField = new SomeObject();

  void MethodCalledMillionsOfTimes()
  {
    // some use of soStaticField
  }
}
```

then there's only one object shared between *all* instances of `C`. No `SomeObject` will have to be collected by the GC.

However, this GC activity is very often not important for your performance. So please **measure** if it is important or not in your case.

Comment: That's enlightening, especially for objects and arrays (reference types), but what about value types...?

Comment: @Fadi As a general rule, if you declare local variables of value type inside some method (and if these local variables are not captured by anonymous method or similar things, and if they are "simple" value types that don't hold references inside themselves), then these values are just put on the stack, and popped from the stack again, so the garbage collector is not on work there. Similarly, updating the value of a value-type field of an existing object, will not create any new objects to be claimed by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 15):

Variables aren't garbage collected. Objects are garbage collected... and they can be garbage collected any time after the runtime can detect that they're no longer referenced by any live code. This can include objects referred to by local variables:

```
public void Foo()
{
    object x = new object();
    // The object can't be collected here...
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    // But it *can* be collected here
    Console.WriteLine("This line doesn't depend on x");
}
```

It's *very* rarely a good idea to change a "natural" design for the sake of garbage collection... something which is the state of a method *isn't* usually naturally part of the state of an object, so turning a local variable into an instance variable is usually a bad idea.

That said, we don't know what those local variables represent, or anything about them - we'll need more context to comment on your *specific* case.

Comment: And reusing instances, which he might want to do, is more complicated than he realizes.

Comment: Actually, there is no specific case, it's just an approach which I'm not sure about, I'm trying to avoid allocating and de-allocating variables in a very sensitive and repeated part of my real-time graphics engine code.

Comment: @Fadi: Your question *sounded* very specific: "There is a piece of my code which is called repeatedly (2000+ each second). To avoid garbage generation and to reduce performance overhead, I moved all local variables to class level" - how is that not a specific case?

Comment: In general, the variables I'm talking about are value variables and managed objects, none of implements IDisposable or use un-managed resources.

Comment: @Fadi: I didn't mention `IDisposable` or unmanaged resources, so I don't see how your comment is relevant.

Comment: Perhaps it helps to say that local variables are managed on the stack, a part of memory separated from the heap. This memory is "freed" (kind of) when the method returns. If local variables are references to objects (on the heap), these objects are located in a heap area called eden. This area is garbage collected often and early.

Comment: @oddparity: Even that isn't necessarily true. Consider variables captured by lambda expressions, or async methods, or iterator blocks... and I thought Eden was JVM-specific, rather than the CLR. (In the CLR it would just be gen-0.)