# Garbage collection from a data access layer

Tags: c#

I am probably missing something here, but I need some clarification from the pros regarding garbage collection.

If I have a referenced object (in this case a DataTable) in one class passed to say a datagridview (keeping the reference live on a form), would the DAL instance stay live, and therefore not be garbage collected? As in the below example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DAL sql=new DAL();
    dgvResult.DataSource=sql.GetData();
}
```

My DAL class

```
private string _dbCon = "server=127.0.0.1;database=northwind;integrated security=true";
public DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable query = new DataTable();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_dbCon))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(GetCommand(), connection))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))    
    {
        adapter.Fill(query);
    }
    return query;
}
```

I am aware there is no error checking, but this is to demonstrate the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local variables and garbage generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301652/local-variables-and-garbage-generation)

Comment: `would the DAL instance stay live,` No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is *"will `DAL` be available for collection after your method finishes"*.

Assuming the only *reference* is from `DAL sql=new DAL()` and there is no other *references* in the class kept by anything else, then as soon as it falls out of scope, the instantiated `DAL` class will be available for collection (when and if the *Garbage Collector* feels like it)

Comment: If I was pedantic I'd point out that it doesn't _need_ to fall out of scope... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cbrumme/lifetime-gc-keepalive-handle-recycling/ ;)

Comment: @mjwills that would be pedantic indeed :) however a worthy note

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the DataTable will stay in memory (not the DAL object though). Until the form is disposed...

Comment: Thanks, I do understand your answer, but the question asks if the DAL instance stays alive, so you should perhaps answer No to prevent future readers confusion :)